# Is there is any ban option for users if he post spam continuously?

Tags: discussion, spam

How to ban spam users one who is posting continuously the spam post?

Even though I flagged his post as spam for number of times, he is posting the spam continuously. How to stop spam users?

Comment: Go through http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam for a full history on this.

Comment: User link broken, so i updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over the last several months, this user has used several different usernames.  The IP address changes, and every time we nuke the account, a new one gets created.  The SE team has adjusted the banned word filters.

Just flag the posts as spam.  If enough people do that, then the posts will go away.  Otherwise, one of the mods will handle it.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17849/badrinath0060 he is again posting spam today - flagging again and agian - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74410/news-for-san-antonio-spurs-vs-memphis-grizzlies-game-4-live

Comment: Every time he posts about some events _watch A vs B live_ . Are these in banned words list ?

Comment: @2-Stroker  The input filters have been adjusted many times.  They work for a few days, then the spam get adjusted to pass.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a typical screen dump: [image].

Notice that there are 9 downvotes and 8 views. You need 125 rep to downvote, but only 15 to flag - so *all* those who downvoted could have flagged.  Also note that it has been up for 31 minutes (long enough for Google to pick it up, which is presumably why he's doing it).  People are obviously downvoting instead of flagging (2-stroker had placed a comment on this, with instructions about flagging, but the downvote button is at the top, and you have to scroll down to see the flag link and the comment).

I think the UX for flagging spam could be improved.

Comment: As an FYI, I'm *pretty* sure that when you flag a post as spam, then it automatically gets a downvote. So there is a chance this was flagged as well as downvoted by some people :-)

Comment: @Chapabu  Yes, spam flags count as a downvote on the question (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work)